# how to pass html code block using ajax and saving it to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to save html with ajax this is my code:

```
var textz = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> test</body> </html>";

 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'ajaxcall.php',
  data: {valeur:encodeURIComponent(textz),userid:userids},
 success: function (dataz) {                            
 //$("#resultat").html(dataz);
      },
  dataType: "HTML"
});
```

it saves it and it looks like :

```
%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0test%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E
```

but in this case I don't know how to change it back to HTML. what would be the opposite for encodeURIComponent in php ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$decoded = urldecode ( $encoded );
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 1):

use rawurldecode() :)

```
rawurldecode($returned_data)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php